# Is possible to create a vb.net or c# app to send notification to mobile using bluetooth without any mobile app?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, vb.net, bluetooth

create a server app in vb.net or C#. It'll run on system with turned on bluetooth. If any mobile with turned on bluetooth devices will comes within the system bluetooth signal, it'll send notification automatically. Is this possible to create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It would not work.

### APNS

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

[image]

### GCM

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

[image]

Push notifications requires to be pushed from Apple's or Google's notifications infrastructures.

For iOS there's local notifications that your app can trigger based on your conditions, but from my knowledge when the Bluetooth connects, your application has to be running and listening for bluetooth changes.

If your app goes into background and got recycled, it would not be able to know when the bluetooth is connected, let alone run your logic to send the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. Your title asks for "without mobile app". The mobile app on the device is what receives the notification. You create the notification on the server (as shown in @Lee's explanation) and your app decides whether to show it to the user or process data behind the scene.

Assuming we disregard the part about "without mobile app", you *CAN* do something similar with iBeacons. Department stores use them for targeted notifications in their app. You walk by a certain rack of clothes with an iBeacon and your app shows a notification that that section is 20%.

As an alternative, you might, somehow, also be able to use a service like Twilio which you can TEXT/MMS information (notification) to someone based on some kind of trigger that you define. This would however require that you already have their phone number and some what to identify that they came within your region.

As a whole, being able to notify people within a proximity that haven't done *something* to subscribe (i.e. download your app, provide contact info) is just plain spammy.